# OData Support in ASP.net core

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

Is oData supported now in ASP.netcore now that version 1 has been released?

I have searched, but I could not find anything that says one way or the other.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit: now available at https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/

It's in the road map, OData Lib has released 7.0.0 which is a breaking change release, OData/WebAPI will release 6.0.0 based on this, after the release, we will consider to support ASP.NET Core. Relative issue: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/772

Comment: the link is not update/clear about where you are with this? Can you shed a light

Comment: According to the issue mentioned in the post, the development of OData for asp.net core hasn't been finished yet. Any alternatives ?

Comment: This lib appears to have .NetCore support: https://gitlab.com/djanosik/moon-odata

Comment: Also, some pre-release code: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/

Comment: @ChrisW This package is not officially supported by Microsoft. It's an individual attempt to port OData to ASP.NET Core, and it hasn't been updated since 2016.

Comment: @FanOuyang What is available is just the OData library, not the webapi integration?

Answer (score 4):

Now at the beginning of December 2017, an official prerelease of OData for ASP.NET Core is available at this MyGet feed: https://www.myget.org/F/webapinetcore/

The releases are currently from nightly builds.

For more information, see this comment on a GitHub issue: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/772#issuecomment-348670747

Still no ETA for beta or stable releases.

---

EDIT: This issue is better to follow to track progress:
https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/939

EDIT 2: Beta1 was released December 22. If used with Swashbuckle, this is a great tip: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1177#issuecomment-358659774

Answer (score 2):

According to the blog OData team at Microsoft
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2018/07/03/asp-net-core-odata-now-available/

There is a a release of OData for ASP.NET Core at :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData

Regards