# Using OData in .net core webapi

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I am trying to hook in OData for .net core web api. Version 6.15 appears to be supporting it (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/6.15.0). Does anyone know how to hook it to the application?

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279552/odata-support-in-asp-net-core

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OData Support in ASP.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279552/odata-support-in-asp-net-core)