# ODataUnrecognizedPathException: Resource not found for the segment 'x' in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, odata

I'm getting this error: ODataUnrecognizedPathException: Resource not found for the segment 'sample'.

Controller Code is like this:

```
[Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Sample")]
    public class SampleController : Controller
    {

        private readonly ISampleBusiness business;
        public SampleController(ISampleBusiness _business)
        {
            business = _business;
        }
        // GET: api/Sample
        [HttpGet]
        [EnableQuery]
        public async Task<IQueryable<ISGUserDTO>> Get()
        {
            var data = await business.GetAll();
            return data.Data;
        }
```

and

Startup Code like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
services.AddOData<ISampleBusiness>(builder => builder.EntitySet<Business.Contracts.DTO.Infra.ISGUserDTO>("Sample"));
```

Configure like this:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
app.UseOData("api");
```

Any ideas what is wrong?

Comment: ASP.NET Core is not yet compatible with latest OData Lib https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/939 and maybe check this discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279552/odata-support-in-asp-net-core. What versions are you using?

Comment: I am using Core 1.1 but my problem is not about installation. I was install and develop but Microsoft.AspNet.Odata nuget give me :  ODataUnrecognizedPathException: Resource not found for the segment 'sample' this exception on any controllers.