# How to Implement Minimal Controller

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, odata, restier

I have an ASP.NET Core 1.1 Web Project.

I have installed [Microsoft.OData.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/) and followed linked "Getting Started" under http://odata.github.io/.

Both the following Links on that page are for .Net 45

- “[Build an OData v4 Service with RESTier Library](http://odata.github.io/RESTier/#01-01-Introduction)”
- “[Build an OData v4 Service with OData WebApi Library](http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#01-02-getting-started)”

This month old [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743055/how-is-it-possible-to-use-odata-in-net-core-application#answer-45752574) links to [Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData) which is NOT owned by Microsoft and was last updated over a year ago.

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279552/odata-support-in-asp-net-core?noredirect=1&lq=1#answer-39283147) implies "OData Support in ASP.net core"

I see this third party solution [AutoODataEF.Core](https://github.com/afgbeveridge/AutoODataEF.Core) to auto generate controllers however.

Lastly, I see this [git issue](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/772#issuecomment-325814316) indicates OData WebAPI for ASP.Net Core is forth coming, but ultimately not currently available.

Assuming I have a Person Model and an EF DbContext.

**How do I implement a minimal OData Controller?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

odata on asp.net core netcoreapp2.0, 20180216

1. install-package Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData -Pre {7.0.0-beta1}
2. in Startup.cs:

   ```c#
   public virtual void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       // ...
       services.AddMvc(); // mvc first
       services.AddOData(); // odata second
   }

   public virtual void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   {
       // ...
       var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(serviceProvider);
       builder.EntitySet<SomeClass>(nameof(SomeClass).ToLower()).EntityType.HasKey(s => s.SomeId);        
       builder.EntitySet<OtherClass>(nameof(OtherClass).ToLower()).EntityType.HasKey(s => s.OtherId).MediaType();   // etc
       var model = builder.GetEdmModel();

       app.UseMvc(routeBuilder =>
       {            
           routeBuilder.Select().Expand().Filter().OrderBy().MaxTop(null).Count();
           routeBuilder.MapODataServiceRoute("ODataRoute", "data", model); // e.g. http://localhost:port/data/someclass?...
           // insert special bits for e.g. custom MLE here
           routeBuilder.EnableDependencyInjection();
           routeBuilder.MapRoute(name: "default", template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"); // enable mvc controllers
       });    
   }
   ```
3. in SomeClassController.cs:

   ```c#
   public class SomeClassController : ODataController // or just plain Controller
   {
       [EnableQuery]
       [HttpGet]
       [ODataRoute("someclass")]
       public List<SomeClass> Get() // this should maybe be an IQueryable wrapped by an IActionResult/OkObjectResult
       {
           List<SomeClass> list = new List<SomeClass>();
           // however you do this
           return list;
       }
   }
   ```