# OData version for .NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, odata, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm willing to use OData in my application using ASP.NET Core, but OData is currently available only in beta version. I would like to know the release date of the stable version of OData for .NET Core.

Comment: Related stackoverflow question: [OData Support in ASP.net core (2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279552/odata-support-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 1):

The team has released a .NET Core oData on NuGet.  You can find it here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/

It's now out of beta; [here's the announcement](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/odatateam/2018/07/03/asp-net-core-odata-now-available/#comment-31795)

---

The ASP.NET implementation is here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData

Comment: There is a YouTube video here that might be helpful as well -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C-PXkbtNI2Q