# Parsing string from a URI querystring always returns null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to retrieve an `int` value from my URI's `querystring` but I've encountered some problems.

I have a request URI that is as follows

```
http://localhost:64813/api/MyController/GetTree?%24filter=parentId%20eq%207
```

I send it via postman, and controller receives it, but I can't access `parentId`'s value. What am I doing wrong?

Here's what I tried so far on my controller... none of these tries is working though…

1) I tried to retrieve a `string` named filter, but it was `null`...

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("GetTree")]
    public IActionResult GetTree(string filter)
    {
        int q = filter.LastIndexOf(" eq ");
        string r = parentId.Substring(q);
        int result = Convert.ToInt32(r);
```

2) I tried to use `[FromQuery]` to access `parentId` from `filter`, but nothing. Always `null` value.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("GetTree")]
    public IActionResult GetTree([FromQuery(Name = "filter")] string parentId)
    {
        int q = parentId.LastIndexOf(" eq ");
        string r = parentId.Substring(q);
        int result = Convert.ToInt32(r);
```

3) Like second try, but I tried to get the whole query instead. As you can guess, the `string` was `null`, again...

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpGet("GetTree")]
    public IActionResult GetNodi([FromQuery] string filter)
    {
        int q = filter.LastIndexOf(" eq ");
        string r = filter.Substring(q);
        int result = Convert.ToInt32(r);
```

Other notable tries:

4) Did as try #2, but I tried to parse `parentId` as an `int` instead of `string`. Nothing, it was always zero as default value, even if i changed the request value.

5) Tried by parsing `filter` as an object (see below) with try #1, try #2 and #3. The string was always `null`.

```
public class NodeReq
{
    public string ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

What have I done wrong? How can I access this querystring `parentId` value?

Comment: why the `%24` ?

Comment: Are you trying to create an oData like url schema?

Comment: @Stefan Actually I'm not pretty sure, since it's a request generated from an angular third-party library (it's named "Devextreme") and sadly I have no control on how it structures the request query… By the way, yes, it uses oData. Here's [an example](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/TreeView/VirtualMode/Angular/Light/)

Comment: ... ok, for OData to work for your own routing schema you need to include routing and libraries. It requires a minimal setup. Have you done that?

Comment: @Stefan Actually no, I haven't done it yet (also because I didn't know that). I'll give a look to the links provided in your answer and I'll let you know!

Comment: Ok, good luck: I did it once myself... it was quite a struggle since the documentation is a bit... minimalistic.

Comment: @Stefan I noticed that… Have you found any example about the Odata controller configuration? I'm trying to find some example on google but nothing...

Comment: @Stefan in the meanwhile, I had an idea… What if I simply access the querystring values like `req.QueryString.Value` and I parse them? Could it work the same?

Comment: Here's some stuff about the subject as well: https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/1177#issuecomment-358659774

Comment: It seems that there is a new release: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/7.0.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL is wrong, ith should be:

```
http://localhost:64813/api/MyController/GetTree?filter=parentId%20eq%207
```

unless you are using [OData](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/os/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-os-part2-url-conventions.html#_Toc372793769), but it doesn't seem so.

If you are using OData, there is no need to escape the characters and it should work with this URL:

```
http://localhost:64813/api/MyController/GetTree?$filter=parentId eq 7
```

If you need to setup OData in your .net core project, I would suggest follow this package:

### update

---

Since your angular setup requires an OData like url schema, and *I have no control on how it structures the request query*; your controllers needs to be compatible with the protocol. More info about this topic can be found here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.OData.Core/

https://github.com/OData/odata.net

[OData Support in ASP.net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39279552/odata-support-in-asp-net-core)

### update:

---

It should be this package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/7.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Query string key name should match the parameter name `filter` and in URL its `%24filter` you will need to removre `%24`

Your URL should be as below

```
http://localhost:64813/api/MyController/GetTree?filter=parentId%20eq%207
```